# How to show detail view controller from split view in fullscreen mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a split view, which has master and detail navigation controllers.
I want my detail VC be able to present its content in fullscreen mode.

that's what I have atm:

```
-(void) tapFullscreenBtn{
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIWindow *topWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: mainWindow.bounds];
    topWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1.0f;

    self.view.frame = mainWindow.bounds;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = mainWindow.bounds;
    
    [topWindow addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [topWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    [self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

unfortunately this code doesn't work. All I have in result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've solved the problem with this:

```
-(void) tapFullscreen {
    if(!_isFullscreenMode)
    {
        MySplitDetailViewController *fullscreenVC = [[MySplitDetailViewController alloc] init];
        fullscreenVC.isFullscreen = YES;
        UINavigationController* fullscreenNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fullscreenVC];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:fullscreenNavVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[mgsplitviewcontroller](http://blog.sabintsev.com/post/31934985014/mgsplitviewcontroller-ios6-compatibility) has the necessary features for you

```
- (IBAction)toggleMasterView:(id)sender; // toggles display of the master view in the current orientation.
```

Comment: This is useless for me because of special UI requirements in my application. :(